# Method to wait when chosen has generated options

Tags: javascript, jquery-chosen

I search an alternative to the method that I used below to wait when the chosen plugin has generated all options before executing an action.

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if($('.chosen-single > span')){
        // do something
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can console the `$('.chosen-single > span')`，and you will know what error occurred.You should use another method to judge the node is shown.